# OAuth2 | ClientCredentialsResourceDetails | deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am new to spring security, and i come across to implement OAuth2 with client_credentials as Grant type.
i am using below piece of code, but i am getting suggestion that **ClientCredentialsResourceDetails, OAuth2RestTemplate & OAuth2AccessToken** are deprecated.

Can someone help with the alternate to this ?

```
 private String getAuthTocken(){
     final ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
     resourceDetails.setClientId("ceapiClientId");
     resourceDetails.setClientSecret("ceapiClientSecret");
     resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
     resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://auth.abcdcommerce.com/oauth-server/oauth/token");

     final OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
     final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();

     final String accessTokenAsString = accessToken.getValue();
     return accessTokenAsString;
 }
```

Comment: can You put here your migration result as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternative is to use the new non-blocking `WebClient` or a `RestTemplate` with an interceptor over the deprecated `OAuthRestTemplate`. Everything in the `spring-security-oauth` artifacts has an end of life road map.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix

The migration guide can be found here,

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide

From the migration guide,

> Spring Security chooses to favor composition and instead exposes an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`, which is useful for creating `RestTemplate`interceptors or `WebClient` exchange filter functions. Spring Security provides `ExchangeFilterFunction` s for both Servlet- and WebFlux-based applications that both leverage this service.

There is a migration example available here,

https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-5-2-migrate

Comment: thanks @Darren, I have implemented it through RestTemplet.

Comment: @piyushvijayvargiya Would you mind sharing example of implementing through RestTemplate ? Thanks.